# AWS Cognito - Sign in via google, shows 'continue to amazoncognito.com'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Sign in via google, shows 'continue to amazoncognito.com'. Is there a way to change that to 'continue to mydomain.com'.
[image: Check the attached image here.]

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. Inside Google's Console -> Under APIs & Services -> OAuth consent screen tab, we adjusted the product name and logo to be displayed and submitted that to be reviewed. But that's under review for a long time. Also not sure if that's gonna change anything.

Comment: Did it change? @DebabrataPramanik I am also having the same issue.

Comment: Hey @SahejMaharjan, I followed the custom domain path given above and it did solve my problem of showing ''continue to amazoncognito.com''. The app is submitted for google verification for a long time, but I am able to use it.

Comment: @DebabrataPramanik I got up to this [point](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/741001929584541710/791188149966602250/unknown.png) still not able to change it. Can you clarify a bit how to change the name?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to change this from `amazoncognito.com` to `domain.io` by doing the following:

1. AWS / User Pools / App Integration / Domain Name

- Set a domain name, ie: `oauth.sandbox.domain.io`
- Create an AWS Managed Certificate for this domain name
- The AWS account I was working with has a `sandbox.domain.io` route53 Hosted Zone, so adding dns verifications and A record aliases was easy.

When the ACM and domain name are added, I was given a cloudfront url.  Add this in your route53 hosted zone as an A record Alias.

2. Google Cloud Config

- Update your Api Credentials to add `oauth.sandbox.domain.io` to your Authorized JavaScript Origins and Authorized redirect URIs.
- Update your OAuth Consent Screen so your Authorized Domains include `domain.io`.

3. Cognito Client App

- Update it to use `oauth.sandbox.domain.io` instead of `${domain_prefix}.auth.${region}.amazoncognito.com`

Comment: What do you mean on the 3rd point, Cognito Client App... ? Where did you did that switch to tell cognito to use domain instead of amazoncognito.com?