# AWS Cognito - Sign in w/ Google shows 'continue to amazoncognito.com'

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Cognito to handle federated logins for a simple webapp, using Google. There is no issue with the login flow or functionality, but there is a branding problem. On the Google login page, instead of "Choose an account to continue to myapp.com", the dialog reads "Choose an account to continue to amazoncognito.com" (see attached screenshot). I'm wondering how to change "amazoncognito.com" to "myapp.com".

For background, this question has been asked at least twice before, but [this instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408769/how-to-change-app-name-while-google-login) received zero answers, and [this instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785893/aws-cognito-sign-in-via-google-shows-continue-to-amazoncognito-com), while it does have some suggestions, is lacking in detail and doesn't solve the problem for me.

Things I've tried:

1. I followed the steps outlined by AWS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html), re: setting up the Cognito hosted UI, but after the fact I realized that the hosted UI is distinct from the popup from Google, so making modifications to that flow would not affect the displayed app name. (But I did set up a sub domain, a new hosted region, DNS records, etc.)
2. I followed the steps in the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785893/aws-cognito-sign-in-via-google-shows-continue-to-amazoncognito-com) Stackoverflow question and made it to the last step, but at this point was not sure where the author was making the suggested change. I tried navigating to the Domain section of App integration under User pools (see second image), but adding my subdomain did not make any changes, and deleting the Cognito domain broke the login flow (when I clicked "Sign in with Google" it took me to the just-deleted Cognito domain, and hence errored out).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as Amazon seems to have under-documented this part of Amplify.

[image: Google login page showing "... continue to amazoncognito.com" instead of "... continue to myapp.com".]

[image: Domain section under App integration under User pools in Cognito.]

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question, but does this help? https://watilde.medium.com/how-to-use-a-custom-domain-of-cognito-hosted-ui-with-amplify-de6b772281ba#:~:text=A%20quick%20fix%20to%20support%20custom%20domain

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from @GregoryLedray did the trick for me. Specifically, I added the below to the section in which I update the AWS config file.

```
awsconfig.oauth.domain = "auth.example.com";
```

For anyone else coming here and starting from scratch (I had already followed the steps outlined in the second question I linked), I suggest following the steps outlined in the [second question I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785893/aws-cognito-sign-in-via-google-shows-continue-to-amazoncognito-com), and supplementing as needed with [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html#cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain-console-step-1) related step-by-step from AWS.